# Render modal from child file

Tags: reactjs

I have two files one is parent file and another is child file. 
Now am trying to call modal code of child file to parent file using `onClick()`.

But am not getting popup on clicking on button. 
can anyone tell me the solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: can you post your code?